# Anomaly detection of two correlated sensors?

Tags: correlation, anomaly-detection

I have gathered two sensor data over a 5 minute time period, and Sensor 1 starts misbehaving at point 4000. What are the statistical ways I can figure out which sensor and at which point it starts sending wrong data?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean with misbehave. If it is the lack of variance, you can use something like:

```
detect_malfunction <- function(x, k = 10, threshold = 0.001) #x is the data from your sensor (numeric vector)
{
  n <- length(x) #number of observations
  y <- rep(F, n) #create logical vector of FALSEs, length n
  for(i in 1:(n-k)){
    if(abs(diff(range(x[i:(i+k)])))<threshold){ #is the range of values within the window of size k smaller than threshold?
      y[i:(i+k)] <- T #elements of y that correspond with erroneous sensor input are set to TRUE
    }
  }
  return(y) #returns logical vetor indicating if the observation was produced when sensor misbehaved (TRUE) or not (FALSE)
}
```

You can set the threshold with the [Chi-squared test for variance in a normal population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Chi-squared_test_for_variance_in_a_normal_population) but it is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks Dan, can you please explain this line: **y <- rep(F, n)**. Also,  what exactly are you computing using **abs(diff(range(x[i:(i+k)])))** ?

Comment: Sorry, I'll add comments to the code.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Could you please describe in general what that code is doing? Resp. what is its purpose?